# Nested For Loop to List Comprehension

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

Given an `OrderedDict` `d`, I'd like to convert a nested `for` loop to a list comprehension. The `OrderedDict` `d` looks like this:

```
import collections
import numpy as np

d = collections.OrderedDict(
    [
        (
            60.0, 
            {
                Timestamp('2016-03-24 00:00:00'): np.nan, 
                Timestamp('2016-03-11 00:00:00'): 2.0173333333333336, 
                Timestamp('2016-02-19 00:00:00'): np.nan, 
                Timestamp('2016-02-26 00:00:00'): np.nan, 
                Timestamp('2016-03-04 00:00:00'): np.nan, 
                Timestamp('2016-03-18 00:00:00'): np.nan, 
                Timestamp('2016-04-01 00:00:00'): np.nan
            }
        ), (
            65.0, 
            {
                Timestamp('2016-03-24 00:00:00'): np.nan, 
                Timestamp('2016-03-11 00:00:00'): np.nan, 
                Timestamp('2016-02-19 00:00:00'): np.nan, 
                Timestamp('2016-02-26 00:00:00'): np.nan, 
                Timestamp('2016-03-04 00:00:00'): 1.8621538461538463, 
                Timestamp('2016-03-18 00:00:00'): np.nan, 
                Timestamp('2016-04-01 00:00:00'): np.nan
            }
        )
    ]
)
```

You'll notice there are *unordered* dicts as values. My goal is to order the "internal" dicts by timestamp, the return the values of the "internal" dict. Finally, I need to combine the key of the "internal" dicts with the values. Result should look like this:

```
[
    [60.0, nan, nan, nan 2.0173333333333336, nan, nan, nan],
    [65.0, nan, nan, 1.8621538461538463, nan, nan, nan, nan]
]
```

The following code prints this out nicely and I want to avoid appending to a list:

```
for k,v in d.iteritems():
    od = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(v.items()))
    for k_, v_ in od.iteritems():
        print k, k_, v_
```

I've also tried the following but it does not sort by key:

```
for row in [[k] + sorted(v.values()) for k, v in d.iteritems()]:
    print row
```

Therefore, looking to convert this to a list comprehension.

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​What's `nan`?

Comment: Sorry, numpy's nan, will edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[[k] + [v_[1] for v_ in sorted(v.items())] for k,v in d.iteritems()]
```

Comment: `TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`

Comment: There was a typo, try again